# How To Make Entire Webpage One Color?

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble changing the background color of my webpage, and cannot seem to find a solution.

I have content on the page, but the black background stops when the content stops. I have tried to extend the content, use the body selector, and universal selector...but none of these work.

Is there any: height: 100% property, so that it can can retain the color for all screens?

Comment: provide us with more details and code

Answer (score 5):

Apply it to the html tag instead.

```
html{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your body content is overflowing the container that has the background color. That's why you see the background color stops but content goes on. To fix the issue ensure that the container contains the content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for vw,vh,vmax,vmin Units

you can use it on your body tag

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh; /*add this to fill the screen*/
  background: red /*set the background color here*/
}
```